# save text input in jupyter notebook in the same textarea

Tags: python, report, jupyter

I'm making a form for reports in Jupyter. I'm loading an xls file, getting all graphs and numbers and structuring the doc. But the problem is that I have to make some textareas for an analyst to comment the results if needed. And, of course, these comments should be saved in the same area.
How can I do it using widgets or maybe some other ways?
Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to save the text typed in the textarea.

Comment: you may import the widget.Text and save it to a variable, say w, then retrieve the text in the text area by w.value

Comment: import ipywidgets as widgets

w = widgets.Textarea(
#     value='Hello World',
    placeholder='give us a tweet to classify,',
    description='tweet:',
    disabled=False
)

Comment: then:

w.value will output the text in the textarea